# Access/SQL Count Distinct Values

Tags: sql, ms-access

Need a quick help with Access. I'm not comfortable around SQL but i will try to explain my problems. I'm trying to create a simple query to Count the Number of distinct of Numbers in the following way:

What I have:

Table 1:

[image]

What I need to have:

Table 2:

[image]

Is it possible?

Comment: Your example is not coherent (wiht green), put it in text (not image) in your post

Comment: `Need a quick help with Access`...then why did you tag it with `mysql`? A bit confusing, that...I will update the tags for you. More info: https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging, https://stackoverflow.com/tour, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: It sounds like you might need to learn about COUNT and GROUP BY queries. But why is the result for Green 3, surely it should be 4?

Comment: Sorry (first time posting so a little lost). No, Green has 3 values because X repeats 2 times so it should be counted has 1. Red is 3 because all of its values are different. Yellow is 1 since all of his values are the same,

Comment: You can edit your question to add those rules, don't hide them in the comments. Your question has an "edit" button just underneath the little blue tags. `first time posting so a little lost`...that's why I listed those links for you to read through so you have a better understanding of the site. I believe at least one of them should have been recommended to you already to read before you posted anything. They exist to help you have a good experience, so please use them. Also, being new here doesn't really explain how you got mysql and access mixed up, but that's a separate issue.

Answer (score 2):

MS Access doesn't support `count(distinct)`.  But you can use a subquery:

```
select col1, count(*)
from (select distinct col1, col2 from t) as t
group by col1
```